# Deductions from combined equation of two circles

Tags: geometry, circles, coordinate-systems

> Given combined equation of two circles
>
> $$x^4+y^4+2x^2y^2-4x^3-4xy^2+2x^2+2y^2+4x-3=0$$

In order to find the **distance between the centres** and **the number of common tangents to the circles**,
one way would be to factorize the equation as

$$(x^2+y^2-1)(x^2+y^2-4x+3)=0$$

However I was hoping whether there was another way to calculate distance between centres and number of tangents using the **coeffecients  of the combined equation**?

In cases where such combined equations are not easily factorisable, using coeffecients would be easier .

*Thus for two circles having equation S1=0 and S2=0 , if we are given (S1)(S2)=0 , then is there a way we can find the above without having to factorize it to (S1)((S2)?*

Comment: Sorry, but I am not able to understand your question. How did you combine the circles? Could you elaborate your question? Where did you start? And what did you do to end up at the first equation?

Comment: @MrYouMath I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the general equation of a circle as
$$x^2+y^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$$
For a system of two circles, the combined equation will be
$$(x^2+y^2+2g_1x+2f_1y+c_1)(x^2+y^2+2g_2x+2f_2y+c_2)=0$$

$$\Rightarrow x^4+2x^2y^2+y^4+2(g_1+g_2)x^3+2(f_1+f_2)x^2y+2(g_1+g_2)xy^2+2(f_1+f_2)y^3+(4g_1g_2+c_1+c_2)x^2+(4f_1f_2+c_1+c_2)y^2+4(g_1f_2+f_1g_2)xy+2(g_2c_1+g_1c_2)x+2(f_2c_1+f_1c_2)y+c_1c_2=0$$

Now, if the given equation is of the form $$x^4+2x^2y^2+y^4+Ax^3+Bx^2y+Axy^2+By^3+Cx^2+Dy^2+Exy+Fx+Gy+H=0$$

Comparing, we can get certain relations which we can use further.

$$A=2(g_1+g_2)$$
$$B=2(f_1+f_2)$$
$$C=4g_1g_2+c_1+c_2$$
$$D=4f_1f_2+c_1+c_2$$
$$E=4(g_1f_2+f_1g_2)$$
$$F=2(g_2c_1+g_1c_2)$$
$$G=2(f_2c_1+f_1c_2)$$
$$H=c_1c_2$$

Distance between the circles is given by
$$(g_2-g_1)^2+(f_2-f_1)^2$$
$$=(g_2+g_1)^2+(f_2+f_1)^2-4(g_1g_2+f_1f_2)$$
$$=\frac{A^2}{4}+\frac{B^2}{4}-(C-H+D-H)$$
$$=\boxed{\frac{A^2}{4}+\frac{B^2}{4}-(C+D-2H)}$$

However, I dont know if it is possible to find no of common tangents fron the coefficients in general.

Comment: The dual conics (given by adjugate matrices) are
$x^2c_1-x^2f_1^2+2xyf_1g_1-2xg_1+y^2c_1-y^2g_1^2-2yf_1+1$ and
$x^2c_2-x^2f_2^2+2xyf_2g_2-2xg_2+y^2c_2-y^2g_2^2-2yf_2+1$
Intersecting we get the common tangents. Taking the Gröbner basis we get a polynomial of degree 4 in $y$. If this has different all real roots the original circles have four tangents, complex conjugate roots reduce the number by two, a repeated root reduces the number by one. It reduces the question to whether one can write the coefficients (polys in $g_1,f_1,c_1,g_2,f_2,c_2$) of this poly in $y$ i.t.o. the $A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H$